# Why is save_post triggered even when I havent saved the post

Tags: theme-development, metabox

I created a meta box I notice that `save_post` seems to be triggered when I land on the page, thus giving me errors like `Undefined index: xxx in /data/www/ae/wp-content/themes/xx/functions.php on line 121`

```
add_action('save_post', function($id) {
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return;
    }
    if (!isset($_POST) || !is_array($_POST)) {
        return;
    }
    update_post_meta($id, 'xxx', sprintf('%f', $_POST['xxx']));
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Why does save_post action fire when creating a new post?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19538/why-does-save-post-action-fire-when-creating-a-new-post/19539#19539)

You're getting the error as you need to check for the existence of `$_POST['xxx']`, rather than just checking if `$_POST` is set (it will *always* be set & an empty array by default).

```
add_action('save_post', function($id) {
    if ( ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) || !isset( $_POST['xxx'] ) )
        return;

    update_post_meta( $id, 'xxx', sprintf( '%f', $_POST['xxx'] ) );
    // run further code
});
```