# publish_post action hook not working

Tags: actions, publish

I've got a really simple problem here, and i'm sure that the solution is going to be really simple.
Here is the code:

```
function the_fat_lady_sings() {
    echo 'this plugin is a far harder than i imagined';
}
add_action( 'publish_post','the_fat_lady_sings' );
```

I just want to echo that line, and it simply does not work.
Please help, i have no idea what's wrong. If I use `init` instead of `publish_post`, it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you did this instead...

```
function the_fat_lady_sings() 
{
    wp_die("this plugin is a far harder than i imageined");
}
add_action('publish_post','the_fat_lady_sings')
```

I think you will see that it does work. The problem you are having with the `echo` is because WordPress processes the submission and then redirects back to form. You'll never see the `echo`ed string. That submit/process/redirect pattern helps to avoid duplicate form submission. There is a name for the technique, which I can't remember. :)

PS: I am hoping somebody will tell me the name of that technique because it driving me a little crazy.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get this?

Comment: That's it, @rrikesh ... thought it had a pronouncable name though. I guess not.

Comment: I don't know, I came across [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/19539/17305), it is called `Post/Redirect/Get` there too...

Comment: In German, we call this _Affenformular_ (monkey form), because 1000 monkeys can submit it 1000 times without ever sending the same request twice.