# save_post action firing before I publish / save the post

Tags: save-post

I'm trying to update a posts meta only after it has been saved or updated.

My function is pretty simple

```
function update_test( $post_id ) {

  update_post_meta($post_id, 'copied', '1');
  update_post_meta($post_id, 'blurb', 'this value updated by save_post action');

}

add_action( 'save_post', 'update_test');
```

When I add a new post at `wp-admin/post-new.php` I can see the two custom fields values have already been updated. The fields themselves exist with Advanced Custom Fields. But shouldn't be updated until after the post has been published / saved and or updated. Why is this updating the fields as soon as the post-new.php form loads?

Comment: duplicate of [Why does save_post action fire when creating a new post?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19538/why-does-save-post-action-fire-when-creating-a-new-post)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A draft or "blank" is saved as soon as you start to create a new post. Those new posts have the `post_status` of `auto-draft`. Check for that to prevent your callback from firing on those "blank" post saves.

```
function update_test( $post_id, $post ) { 
  if (isset($post->post_status) && 'auto-draft' == $post->post_status) {
    return;
  }
  update_post_meta($post_id, 'copied', '1');
  update_post_meta($post_id, 'blurb', 'this value updated by save_post action');
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'update_test', 1, 2);
```

You may also want to check for the `DOING_AJAX` and `DOING_AUTOSAVE` constants.

Comment: Thanks I ended up checking if the post_status was publish

Comment: For whatever reason, `wp_is_post_revision` and `wp_is_post_autosave` were always false in my plugin, even when creating a new post, but this works a charm. Thanks!