# Saving metadata of related post on save_post

Tags: custom-field, save-post

here is the scenario:

- Custom Post Type "shows"
- Custom Post Type "reviews"

Reviews are "child" of shows so that every review has a custom field with the ID of the parent "show".

Since a review has also a custom field with a rating value I'd like upon save to create/update a custom field for the parent post (show) with the average rating.

I create a function which returns a numeric value for the average rating.

I'm trying to use save_post action hook without success. Here is my code:

```
function save_show_rating( $post_id ) {

    /*
     * In production code, $slug should be set only once in the plugin,
     * preferably as a class property, rather than in each function that needs it.
     */
    $slug = 'reviews';

    // If this isn't a 'book' post, don't update it.
    if ( $slug != $_POST['post_type'] ) {
        return;
    }

    // Retrieving parent ID 
    $parent_id = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_wpcf_belongs_fulldome-shows_id', true );

    // Saving average rating
    $average = average_rating_num_func();

    // Check if the field already exists
    $custom_field = get_post_meta( $parent_id, 'average_rating', TRUE );

    // Update parent's metadata.
    if ( $custom_field != '') {
        update_post_meta( $parent_id, 'average_rating', $average );
    } else {
        add_post_meta($parent_id, 'average_rating', $average, true);
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_show_rating' );
```

Hope you can help.
Thank you guys

Best regards
Carlo

Comment: Hello, Caletto. What have you done to troubleshoot this code; how do you know that it's not working? Can you confirm that the `save_show_rating()` function is firing when you save a review? Is `average_rating_num_func()` returning what you expect it to? Are you positive you registered your "reviews" post type using `'reviews'` as the post-type key?

Comment: Hi @boscho . Thanks for your comment. Well actually I don't know if save_show_rating() is firing at the right time... for sure I check the database "wp_postmeta" table and not find any record for "average_rating" saved. The "Reviews" post type, as the "Shows", are created with WP-Types plugin and the slug I set for them has been checked several times to avoid ordinary mistakes. The average_rating_num_func() is returning a numeric value with 2 decimals and I already tried it inside a template file. What I don't say is the code I'm using is a sort of mod of the one you can find in the WP codex

Comment: Alright, cool - now we have a starting point to work from. Another question: in what file is this code you've posted? The active theme's `functions.php` or a plugin perhaps? If you haven't done so already (and you're not in a production environment), enable WP's debug mode by adding this line to your `wp-config.php` before the "stop editing" comment: `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );`. This will enable the output of WP debugging info & errors.

Comment: You can use [PHP's `die()`/`exit()` function](http://us2.php.net/die) to kill script execution with a message. You should avoid using it in production code as it's messy and blunt, but it can be useful for debugging purposes. First let's check if the function is getting called when a post (of any type) is saved. At the top of your function before the `if` statement, add this line: `die( 'Death at save_show_rating( ' . $post_id . ' )' );`.

Comment: Now whenever `save_show_rating()` is called (which should be when the `save_post` WP action is fired), PHP should kill the script and display the message `Death at save_show_rating( {value of $post_id} )`. Now go into your dashboard and save a review - did PHP `die()` and display the message? If so, that implies that `save_show_rating()` is indeed getting called when it should be.

Comment: Hi @boscho sorry for the delay and thanks for your patience! So: 1. yes the code is in the functions.php file and 2. wp_debug il already "true" since I'm in a development stage. I edit the function as you said and I get the die display message on "add new review" click... I think it's a bit earlier than expected... ain't it?

Comment: Hey @Carletto - no worries regarding delays! It certainly seems earlier that you'd think it would fire, doesn't it? This happens because [as soon as you load up `wp-admin/post-new.php` WordPress creates a new post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19538) with the `revision` `post_type` and `auto-draft` `post_status`. You can verify this by moving your `die()` call to below that first conditional (the `if` statement); now if the `post_type` is anything other than `review`, the function will return before your call to `die()`.

Comment: I'll be back in a couple hours - if you're online then, we'll crack open a chatroom and work this out. If not I'll add the next troubleshooting steps to these comments

Comment: I'm online of course... I'm sending you an hangout message. When you're about to start just let me know! Thanks!

Comment: If moving the `die()` below the `if` didn't result in PHP only `die()`ing when you save a review, we need to verify that `review` is really the `post_type` that WordPress recognizes the CPT(Custom Post Type) with. If moving that call to `die()` resulted in PHP only `die()`ing when saving a review, then the review CPT's `post_type` is `review`, which means that the rest of your function has been executing at the proper time.

Comment: The next thing you should do is verify the values of the variables in your function body - the most accessible tool for this is [the `var_dump` function](http://www.php.net//manual/function.var-dump.php). Make sure each of `$parent_id`, `$average`, and even `$custom_field` are what you would expect them to be. You can accomplish this by dumping each variable after it's set, i.e.  `$average = average_rating_num_func();` `echo("\n\$average:\n");`  `die( var_dump( $average ) );` This will print out information regarding each variable's structure, value, and type.

Comment: Usually it wouldn't be necessary to `die()` when you `var_dump()`, but WordPress performs some page redirects during `save_post` - if the variable dumps to the screen before one of those page redirects, it's possible that the redirect will load another page before the dumped variable information is displayed. By `die()`ing when you dump the variable, you make sure that when PHP prints that variable it stops all script execution, and WordPress cannot redirect away from the page before the variable information is displayed.

Comment: If `$average` is not the value that you expect it to be, then the problem likely lies in your `average_rating_num_func()` and you should [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/146082/edit) to add it's contents. If `$parent_id` is an empty string `''`, it could indicate that whatever is responsible for setting the `'_wpcf_belongs_fulldome-shows_id'` meta-field is not functioning properly.