# Action hook save_post for newly created posts - $post object data is all empty

Tags: hooks, slug

When a post is created, I need to auto-generate a PDF version of the post. The problem is that the global $post object is mostly empty except for the post ID. I need to get the newly created post's slug because the name of the PDF file needs to match the slug of the page.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_save_post' );
function my_save_post($post_id) {
    global $post;

    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

    $pdf = new PDF();
    $pdf->createPDF( $post );

    // Debug
    print_r( $post );
    die();
}
```

If I Publish the new post, then go back and update the post, the $post variable contains all the correct data, but if it's a new post the object is empty. I've also tried the `edit_post` and `post_updated` hooks, but in every case the slug and most other data doesn't exist in the $post variable.

*Updated hook and result of `print_r($post)`:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_save_post', 10, 3 );
function my_save_post( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;
    if ( 'auto-draft' === $post->post_status ) return;

    $pdf = new PDF();
    $pdf->createPDF( $post );

    // Debug
    print_r( $post );
    die();
}
```

And here's the result of the `print_r`:

```
WP_Post Object
(
    [ID] => 593
    [post_author] => 1
    [post_date] => 2017-11-20 18:29:36
    [post_date_gmt] => 2017-11-20 18:29:36
    [post_content] => 
    [post_title] => 
    [post_excerpt] => 
    [post_status] => publish
    [comment_status] => closed
    [ping_status] => closed
    [post_password] => 
    [post_name] => 593
    [to_ping] => 
    [pinged] => 
    [post_modified] => 2017-11-20 18:29:36
    [post_modified_gmt] => 2017-11-20 18:29:36
    [post_content_filtered] => 
    [post_parent] => 0
    [guid] => http://localhost:8888/testsite/?post_type=publication&p=593
    [menu_order] => 0
    [post_type] => publication
    [post_mime_type] => 
    [comment_count] => 0
    [filter] => raw
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time that `save_post` fires it is when WordPress is creating an auto draft. See [Why does save_post action fire when creating a new post?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19538/why-does-save-post-action-fire-when-creating-a-new-post?rq=1)

To fix, just check to see if the passed `$post` variable has a post status of auto-draft.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_save_post', 10, 3 );
function my_save_post( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;
    if( 'auto-draft' === $post->post_status ) return;
    $pdf = new PDF();
    $pdf->createPDF( $post );
}
```

Comment: I actually tried that already, but $post still didn’t contain most of the post data. I also tried adding another check after that to make sure $post->post_name was not empty, and it never passed that check when I published the post until I pressed the Update button.

Comment: You're checking on the passed $post variable and not the global $post variable? Because in your sample code, you're using the global.

Comment: Yep, I changed that function to include all 3 parameters and added the `10, 3` bit to the add_action. I'll update my question to include the updated function and the result of `print_r($post)`. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior. Have you tested the above code on a fresh install of WordPress with no plugins and a default theme?

Comment: Ya know, I think your instincts are right. I'm using Advanced Custom Fields and when I saved a normal `post` (not a custom post type) the $post variable contained more data. It still didn't contain the `post_name`, but this tells me this problem has to do with the custom fields. Thanks for taking the time to help me get to the bottom of this :)